# Storing images from node to aws s3 to be deployed in heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, amazon-s3

Hi I would like to store images in amazon s3. I am making a react application with node js and express at the back end. I have a code which is saving the images locally, in images folder as desired. I am using jimp library to convert the images into black and white. What i want is to store these black and white images directly to aws instead of saving to local hdd. I need to do this because in the end the app has to be deployed to heroku, and heroku is not able to read images from local hdd.

Here is the code through which i was able to store images in a particular directory as required.

```
const input = req.body.input;
google.list({
    keyword: input,
    num: 15,
    detail: true,
})
.then(function (res) {
    res.map((data,index)=>{
      const url = data.url;
      const extension = url.split('.')[url.split('.').length-1]
      const foldername=input

      Jimp.read(url, function (err, image) {
          image.resize(250, 250)
          .greyscale()      
         .write(path.join(__dirname,"../../public/images/"+foldername+"/"+foldername+index+"."+extension));
        });
      });

    })
}).catch(function(err) {
          res.send('There was some error')
      })
```

I need to store images in the same path ie., awsbucketname/foldername/foldername.jpg. I tried converting the image to buffer but still i don't understand how to proceed with it. Some one please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I have no practical experience with Jimp!)

It seems like you are on the right track with writing the image [to a buffer](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp#writing-to-buffers) instead of a local file. Once you have initialized the AWS SDK and instantiated the S3 interface, it should be easy to pass the buffer to the [`upload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) function. Something along the lines of:

```es6
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'yourBucketName' } });

// ...

Jimp.read(url, (err, image) => {
  const bucketPath = `/${foldername}/${index}.${extension}`;
  image.resize(250, 250)
    .greyscale()      
    .getBuffer(Jimp.AUTO).then(buffer => {
      s3.upload({ Key: bucketPath, Body: buffer })
        .then(() => console.log('yay!'));
    });
  }
);
```

This is just a sketch of course, missing error handling etc.